# How to drag and drop input field Text and Display

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

[This is unity editor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE6wy.png)

I want to drag the input field on inspector but unable to do that.
code is:

```
public InputField inputField;
private const string PlayerNamekey ="PlayerName";
private string PlayerName = null;

m_HighScore = m_Points;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt(HighScoreKey, m_HighScore);
PlayerName = inputField.text;
PlayerPrefs.SetString(PlayerNamekey,PlayerName);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
HighScore.text = $"High Score: {PlayerName}: {m_HighScore}";
```

I just want to drag and show input. But I am unable to drag it and drop on inspector.

Comment: try "public TMP_InputField inputField;"

Comment: `InputField` != `TMP_InputField` ... they are completely different components

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the wrong data type to the input field and check if the component is on the gameobject that you're trying to drag to the reference. A print of the input field game object would help to give a better answer.